# Using the Windows 7 installer environment to add missing USB drivers to the OOBE

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, windows-installation, windows-pe

I'm installing Windows 7 on my computer. It's fairly modern (2020), uses UEFI (with legacy support), and has no PS/2 ports or disk drive and uses a modern chipset. I used NTLite on a separate installation of Windows 10 (on my first hard drive) to create a disk image which would include USB and modern chipset drivers for use during installation of Windows 7. I burned my custom ISO to a USB drive and booted it in Legacy mode, making sure my second hard drive had no partitions and was converted to MBR.

The first phase of the setup (the part that takes place entirely on the USB drive) worked great. But as soon as I had to boot Windows 7 from the hard drive, the USB drivers were no longer working and I could not control the setup from there. And yes, I did try all of the USB compatibility options in the BIOS to no effect. What's worse is that I can't boot back in to Windows 10 on a separate (GPT) hard drive because the UEFI boot loader was mysteriously erased, and going back to UEFI mode in the BIOS does not display any boot options.

Since I have no bootable operating systems and cannot continue the Windows 7 setup without USB drivers, I concluded that I must use the Command Prompt in the Windows 7 install disk (on a USB drive in this case) to add USB drivers to the Windows 7 installation on the hard drive. What is the most straightforward way to do that?

Comment: "Windows 7 on my computer. It's fairly modern (2020)" - this doesn't exist. What are you installing?

Comment: @harrymc because I prefer Windows 7, and it's possible to install it on my computer. I just did something wrong and I need help correcting it with the tools I have available.

Comment: Using Windows 7 on modern hardware may fail, because companies no longer provide for it drivers for new types of devices. I suggest to fix instead your Windows 10 installation.

Comment: @harrymc I doubt that I could use a CSM version of Windows 7 to repair the boot loader of a UEFI Windows 10 installation. That will have to wait.

Comment: “because the UEFI boot loader was mysteriously erased” - It likely was erased just not accessible since you have CSM enabled, or it was erased, since you converted to MBR. Yes; You need to manually add the USB 3 drivers to the WinPE. This process is well documented

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think you understand. WinPE on the flash drive works fine with my USB peripherals, like I said before. The problem is the OOBE (the phase of setup that takes place on the hard drive), where the USB drivers do not load, which is not something I can find any information about online. And yes, I did try turning off legacy mode to boot from my GPT drive, but there were no boot entries available after I did that.

Comment: It might be safer to use Win 7 in a virtual machine.